# Git shortlog with date/time

Tags: git, git-log

It is possible to get a git shortlog result with the date/time of the commit?

Otherwise is it possible to get git log to group commits and sum them by author and print out only the message and time?

Comment: Great question!!
How do I add date time to each result in this list:

git log -4 --pretty=format:%h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is possible to get a git shortlog result with the date/time of the commit?

Yes, using the `--format=format:%cI` option.  See "PRETTY FORMATS" in the git-log man page for details.

> Otherwise is it possible to get git log to group commits and sum them by author and print out only the message and time?

Not that I can find.  You could [whip something up with libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/ex/HEAD/log.html).

Comment: this doesn't work
git log -4 --pretty=format:%h --format=format:%cI
and this doesn't work
git log -4 --pretty=format:%hcI 
and this doesn't work
 git log -4  --format=format:%cI

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons What about them "doesn't work" and what does that have to do with this answer?

Comment: I was looking for the answer to "How do I git log with short commit hash + date/time?" and got it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868396/how-do-i-git-log-with-short-commit-hash-date-time