# How do I git log with short commit hash + date/time?

Tags: git

Let's say I do this command:
 git log -4 --pretty=format:%h

How do I add date/time to each result?

Comment: With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), you also have [`git show -s --pretty=reference <commit>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59380120/6309) which can be of interest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For *Committer Date* use `%cd`:

```
git log -4 --pretty=format:"%h - %cd"
```

-

For *Author Date* use `%ad`:

```
git log -4 --pretty=format:"%h - %ad"
```

-

For more options refer [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History).

Comment: only problem, those dates are verbose, like `Fri Jul 22 16:51:46 2022 +0200`. `%cr` gives a relative date, and `%cs` gives a short date, but I haven't figured out how to have a short time, like `16:51` instead of `16:51:46 2022 +0200`...

Comment: this documents the `--pretty`  formats https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Comment: `%cI` is ok as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255959/153144
This works ok in my time zone: `git log --pretty=format:'%cI %h %s %an' -n 20 | sed 's/:[0-9][0-9]+02:00//'`