# How to show date and time of a commit by hash

Tags: git

I used `git reflog` to identify a hash for when I created a particular branch. I got the hash of `fe1ddcdef`. I haven't pushed this branch to the remote yet. I'm now trying to find the date and time for when `fe1ddcdef` took place. `git reflog` only shows me:

`fe1ddcdef HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from master to handoff`

which does not have a date or time.

`git log` is far too verbose, since it contains commits from all of my colleagues and I can't easily find the needle of `fe1ddcdef` in that haystack.

How can I simply find the date and time of commit `fe1ddcdef`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Simply use :

```
git show fe1ddcdef
```

… to display the content of the commit. Actually, once you have any expression that identifies a commit object, you can use it in all places that require a revision. These expressions can be an hexadecimal hash (even partial), a branch name or a tag name. It can also be one of these, associated to one or many operators such as "^", or "~", or "@".

This means that you can also use `git log fe1ddcdef` to get the full history of the branch starting from this point.

If you want to get only date and time of it and nothing else, you can type :

```
git show --no-patch --no-notes --pretty='%cd' fe1ddcdef
```

Replace `'%cd'` by `'%h %cd %s'` to add hash summary and commit's subject message.

Comment: `%cI` is more appropriate for scripts, for example for use in `tar --mtime`.

Answer (score 15):

You can try **--date**

```
git reflog --date=iso
```

It will give you **timstamp** with each hash:

```
cd7c3721 HEAD@{2021-03-25 16:47:42 +0100}: commit: Updated paths
644bc38f HEAD@{2021-03-25 01:28:32 +0100}: commit: Add feign router
c7d62f34 HEAD@{2021-03-25 01:14:42 +0100}: commit: Add feign config
fdaedc9e HEAD@{2021-03-25 01:12:31 +0100}: commit: Add test config
```

You can also make your own formats using [git pretty formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats). Also look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369254/is-there-a-way-to-cause-git-reflog-to-show-a-date-alongside-each-entry) for more options.

Comment: Note that this will show the *reflog* timestamp, which is when the OP had that commit checked out. That might be what he wants.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm now trying to find the date and time for when `fe1ddcdef` took place

"Took place" is not well defined, but I can note that every commit has two date-and-time stamps associated with it: the *author date* and the *commit date*.

Typically these two are the same, unless you use any of the various options that copy commits, in which case the author timestamp is the date it was first committed and the committer timestamp is when that particular commit was made.

Both timestamps are under the complete control of the user.  Typically people don't override them, though, so that they're as accurate as their own computer's clock (i.e., not very).

To see both dates, use, e.g.:

```
git log --no-walk --pretty=fuller fe1ddcdef
```

To see just one, you can leave out the format, or use `git show <hash>` (which also shows a diff).  To get *just* the date or dates, use `--pretty=format:<directives>` or `--format=<directives>`.  The directives that print the author date have the form `%a<letter>` and those that print the committer date have the form `%c<letter>`, where the `<letter>` part is one of `d`, `D`, `r`, `t`, `i`, or `I`.  For more details see the [PRETTY FORMATS section of the `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats).

Answer (score 5):

The normalized way to reference a commit is `abbreviated hash (subject, date)`, without the time. It is called a "reference".

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "`git log`" family learned "`--pretty=reference`" that gives the name of a commit in the format that is often used to refer to it in log messages.

And that format is close to what you are looking for.

See [commit 3798149](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3798149a74f0c2b84b42b108b4fc6ce28c6ab023), [commit 1f0fc1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f0fc1db8599f87520494ca4f0e3c1b6fabdf997), [commit 618a855](https://github.com/git/git/commit/618a855083fbd3b8f9491ec8b32b39bdea91868d), [commit ac52d94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac52d9410e5fad8d0bffa95e70e514c3fbd96871), [commit 3e8ed3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e8ed3b93e9b46eb6fe61589482751728865de57), [commit 4982516](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4982516451ed4979bc7fc1a7f002fc310b060118), [commit f0f9de2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0f9de2bd71b41afeb2a2a77a681a15a83246a62), [commit fb2ffa7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb2ffa77a6cbd0f4b996befe372f1c7a1b881e66), [commit bae74c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bae74c9dfbacce38dcd8cc7c2737af11a85d9906), [commit bd00717](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd00717eab1f2c9e9f50d8bca3fa81f7f953f283) (20 Nov 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
See [commit 0df6211](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0df621172d830adf36d4226b98f9cf4006d183a6) (20 Nov 2019) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d37cfe3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d37cfe3b5c7ef64aff0459ce2730464120c97f30), 10 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0df621172d830adf36d4226b98f9cf4006d183a6): provide short date format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> Add the placeholders `%as` and `%cs` to format author date and committer date, respectively, without the time part, like `--date=short` does, i.e. like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Why?
Because of contribution and patch:

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f0fc1db8599f87520494ca4f0e3c1b6fabdf997): implement '`reference`' format
>
> <sup>Based-on-a-patch-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> **The standard format for referencing other commits within some projects** (such as [git.git](https://github.com/git/git)) **is the `reference` format**.
> This is described in [`Documentation/SubmittingPatches`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f0fc1db8599f87520494ca4f0e3c1b6fabdf997/Documentation/SubmittingPatches#L143-L150) as:

> If you want to reference a previous commit in the history of a stable branch, use the format "**abbreviated hash (subject, date)**", like this:

> ```
> ....
> ```

```
    Commit f86a374 (pack-bitmap.c: fix a memleak, 2015-03-30)
    noticed that ...
....
```

> Since this format is so commonly used, standardize it as a pretty format.

The [`pretty-formats` documentation now includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f0fc1db8599f87520494ca4f0e3c1b6fabdf997/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L66-L75):

> '`reference`'

> ```
> <abbrev hash> (<title line>, <short author date>)
> ```

> This format is used to refer to another commit in a commit message and is the same as `--pretty='format:%C(auto)%h (%s, %ad)'`.
> By default, the date is formatted with `--date=short` unless another `--date` option is explicitly specified.
> As with any `format:` with format placeholders, its output is not affected by other options like `--decorate` and `--walk-reflogs`.

---

Before Git 2.25, as shown in [WisdmLabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993125/wisdmlabs)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35869362/6309), you might do:

```
git show -s --date=short --pretty='format:%h (%s, %ad)' <commit>
```

Now (Git 2.25+):

```
git show -s --pretty=reference <commit>
```

---

Example with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), and "`log --format=...`" that show timestamps in various formats.

See [commit 3593ebd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3593ebd3f502d28eb405ce502cd9fbd743afc3fe), [commit fbfcaec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbfcaec8d82adf9994a88a49e9b12f2ecffc4626) (25 Apr 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e5d99d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5d99d378bc8207d7fccab678be7e7135f0606d1), 07 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pretty tests`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbfcaec8d82adf9994a88a49e9b12f2ecffc4626): simplify `%aI/%cI` date format test
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change a needlessly complex test for the %aI/%cI date formats (iso-strict) added in [466fb67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/466fb6742d7fb7d3e6994b2d0d8db83a8786ebcf) ("`pretty`: provide a strict ISO 8601 date format", 2014-08-29, Git v2.2.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ceeacc501bc64dcdff180a9250bf2fcea3582837)) to instead use the same pattern used to test `%as/%cs` since [0df6211](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0df621172d830adf36d4226b98f9cf4006d183a6) ("`pretty`: provide short date format", 2019-11-19, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d37cfe3b5c7ef64aff0459ce2730464120c97f30) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad05a3d8e5a6a06443836b5e40434262d992889a)).